# is it posible to include page numbers with onendpage events

Tags: itext

I am working through some more examples from the new itextpdf website...(good job by the way) I normally add page numbers in headers and footers as a second pass over the document once it is completed.

Is there a way to add the page number dynamically in a header or footer as an onendpage event?

Clearly this could be done by using a counter with document.addPage(), but text may create new pages all by itself when given a large text block so this would then not work.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you very much for your comment on the new web site!

You can indeed get the current page number in the `onEndPage()` method and add it to the document. Please take a look at the [MovieHistory2](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-5#228-moviehistory2.java) example, or better yet: the [MovieCountries1](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-5#225-moviecountries1.java) example.

Allow me to simplify the `onEndPage()` method of these examples:

```
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    Rectangle rect = writer.getPageSize();
    ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
        Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(
            String.format("page %d", writer.getPageNumber())),
            (rect.getLeft() + rect.getRight()) / 2, rect.getBottom() - 18, 0);
}
```

In this snippet, `writer.getPageNumber()` will give you the current page number. I add it to the page at the bottom-middle.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, so I see that by getting the DirectContent, it already then knows which is the current page number. As ever your answers are both a solution and a place for further learning and exploration...